How can I use a non-static method across unity scripts?
The error is occurring in the first code block, line 21, where I'm trying to compare price with available cash. While GetPrice() works (details in 3rd block), GetCash() shows this error:

Cannot access non-static method 'GetCash' in static context

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DBayManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void PurchaseCabinet(Cabinet cabinet)
    {
        if (GameManager.GetCash() < cabinet.GetPrice())
        {
            
        }
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int nightNum;
    public int cash;
    public float popularity;
    private List<Cabinet> cabinetList;
    
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void NewGame()
    {
        nightNum = 1;
        cash = 100;
        popularity = 1;
    }

    public int GetCash()
    {
        return cash;
    }

    public void ChangeCash(int amount)
    {
        cash += amount;
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cabinet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string name;
    public int price;
    public Vector3 gameSpawnArea;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public int GetPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}


Please don't tag your titles with keywords. See [ask] and take the [tour].

well you try to access GameManager.GetCash() as if it was a static method .. but it isn't .. it is an instance method public int GetCash() ... so the same way as for the cabinet.GetPrice() you need to get a reference to your GameManager instance
